# Do browsers ignore suffixes?

Tags: php, html, url, redirect

By mistake, I did not add the suffix `.php` when I wrote a URL into the browser during a check on my website. The browser ignored it and simply returned the page as if I had added the `.php` suffix, anyway! Is this normal? Do all modern browsers see a URL like `www.website.com/thispage` and simply go to `thispage.php` or `thispage.html`, if they exist?

Comment: This is not the doing of your browser, your website just handles both urls.

Comment: The browser doesn't know anything about suffixes. It just sends the URL to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Requests go to the server.

Any basic URL in the address bar of a browser make an HTTP request to the server defined by the domain (or hostname). So, `http://www.something.com/here/there.x` sends a whole bunch of info (in the "HEADER" of the request) to the IP registered for the `www` subdomain of `something.com`. That server gets the request, which in the header includes information about your browser, IP, type of request, the full address requested, any submitted data from a form, etc.

#### Your server's http engine decides what to do with it

Apache, nginx, iis, are different types of HTTP servers who's whole purpose are to listen for such requests, and decide what to do about them.

Typically, this includes setting some degree of defaults, for instance:

1. match the domain to a directory

   - something.com: `/var/www/site1`
   - strange.com: `/var/www/site2`
   - default: `/var/default`
2. match the path (everything *after* the '/' following the domain) to a file

   - check for a matching `.html` file
   - check for a matching `.php` file
3. Check permissions and authentication
4. Execute the file according to config

   - send the php file to a php process, and reroute the output
   - simple grab and dump the contents of images, txt, and html files.
5. Send a response according to what was just executed.

This is ***DRASTICALLY*** simplified, and there are *many many* layers and specifics, but I'm trying to keep this as simple as the question.

#### You tell apache (or whatever) what to do.

Apache can be configured to return a styleized google search for cats, any time anyone requests `http://blah.something.com/[anything]/*.good. It can be configured to do just about anything you want it to, based on the url you send it. The browser only decides what is sent.

Comment: As I asked Onyx, does that mean that when the server returns "www.blah.com/blah.php" when I just ask for "blah.com/blah" no matter which browser is being used? Also, love the cat example!

Comment: _probably_, but it is important to note that the server can be configured to do this for any type of file, or even generate it's own HTML response to list contents of a folder. Additionally, it is possible to configure it to change its behavior depending on what's in the request (browser, ip, authentication, etc.), such it that it will render php files for macs, and html for pc for instance.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely up to the web server, and it's configuration, as to how a URL is handled. Web servers like Apache, NGinx, Cherokee, Litespeed, etc all have different mechanisms for what happens when a URL request hits it, and then what it decides to do afterwards. 
For instance, you could have your web server attempt to add .php and .htm and .html suffixes to the requested url, in order to try to be helpful. Or simply serve up the 404 page, or send the request to the home page - eg index.php.

Comment: So if the server does it for one browser, it does it for all? It's not about the browser brand or version at all?

Comment: Usually, yes, unless the browser in question has some sort of strange plugin that mangles the request on the way through...but you cannot cover all edge cases like that. 
FYI : Some older browsers, particularly like IE, have issues with things like compression (eg. gzip ) or image display(transparent PNG), but NOT with the URL request. So be aware that not all browsers and versions are created equal.